# iOS Push Notification without adding UDID in provisioning profile for testflight beta

Tags: apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, testflight, udid

I am using Testflight Beta invitation mail to install app on iOS 8.1 iPhone 6.
App is getting installed however push notifications are not being received.
Do I need to add UDID in provisioning profile for push notifications to work ?
If so, How Push notifications will work for Apple's External Testers on Testflight Beta ?
Because this feature doesnt need to add UDIDs of devices in provisioning profiles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to add UDID in provisioning profile for push notifications to work ? If so, How Push notifications will work for Apple's External Testers on Testflight Beta ?

There is no need of linking UDID's to the provisioning profile for Push Notifications under Testflight Beta External Testers.

There would be some other problems releated to push notifications. These can be:

- Your certificate (PEM file) is not correct on the server end.
- You are using sandboxing.gateway for sending push notifications. Then remove the sandboxing environment for this.
- The device notifications settings are on for your app.
- The device token you are sending to server is correctly used for sending right push notifications.
- Some times push notifications get delayed due to some server issues.

Hope it helps.

Harry